# How to select the dataframe between two give values for a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the avocado dataset.
How to find the mean of 'Total Volume' from 29 dec 2015 to 13 april 2018 of Boston 'region'.

I am trying to calculate it by `df.loc()`

```
import pandas as pd
data_new = data.loc[(data['Date']>='2015-12-29')&(data['Date']<='2018-04-13')&(data['region']=='Boston')]
print(data_new.mean())
```

Is it right or I have to provide the axis for the `mean()`?

dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices

Comment: _Consider the avocado dataset._ What avocado dataset? _Is it right or I have to provide the axis for the mean()?_ That's pretty easy to figure out, does it produce the correct result?

Comment: this question is from hackerrank. The problem statement was to calculate the mean of 'Total Volume' from 29 dec 2015 to 13 april 2018 of Boston 'region'. the above solution was giving the wrong answer verdict.

Comment: That's information which should be in your post, then.

Comment: @RishiSahu you're pretty close my man, just add the column name to the end and add `.mean()`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not put the column there, then it would return the mean of all columns. Btw one prettier way for convenience would be taking out the condition part if you have many. It would be read easier.

```
condition = (data['Date']>='2015-12-29')&\
                     (data['Date']<='2018-04-13')&\
                     (data['region']=='Boston')
mean_total_vol = data[condition]['Total Volume'].mean()
```